# What design pattern should I use to combine three data sources that communicate in a chain?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, mediator

**Specific Questions:**

1. What is the best design pattern or strategy for this particular problem?
2. How can I prevent potential cascading effects & re-writing the code?

**Details:**

I am developing a program in which I have three data sources (A, B, C).
In order to grab data from B, I need information from A.
In order to pull data from C, I need information from B.

**Current Approach:**

**Description:**

I used four classes. A mediator class that handles the passing of data from A, B, & C. Then, a separate class for A, B, & C that handles extracting, formatting, sub-setting, etc.

**Process Flow:**

1. Inside the mediator class I instantiate classes A, B, & C.
2. I run a function inside the mediator class called create_A_files().
3. The data from A that B needs is then passed as an argument to B's create_B_files(A_necessary_data) function.
4. Finally, the same is done from B to C through a create_C_files(B_necessary_data) function.

**Problems with Current Approach:**

I am fighting cascading effects. Any changes I make in A propagate and cause errors & bugs in B & C.
Therefore, I have to go back and rewrite B & C to accommodate the changes from A.

Thank you in advance for your help!
Narnia649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure your 3 parts are well isolated and covered by tests. Having a good test suite is the best tool you can use to prevent issues when updating the code.

Then, think about this: each piece is actually independent:

- A is producing some output but doesn't really care where it goes.
- B is manipulating some data but doesn't really care where it comes from.
- C is the same as B

now, I can't really say how to do this in python, but in .NET I would start by identifying the right interface for all the parts and then build an orchestrator that would take care of the global workflow.

And of course tons of tests :)